# How can I trace/snoop route changes?

Tags: macos, dtrace

I have a program that changes the routes on my mac. I want to trace what it is doing.

With some dtrace/dtruss, the best I can get is something like:

`2455/0x833e:  stat64("/sbin/route\0", 0x7FFEE9DB0740, 0x0)              = 0 0`
But this isn't good enough. I want to know what arguments `route` is being called with.

I've been doing a log of googling. I found a PDF of a talk (dtrace_workshop01_slides.pdf). It says:

> DTrace can snoop route changes live

that'd be nice! But the slides don't say how to do it.

I turned off macOS SIP temporarily, and dtrace seems to work in general. I don't need the solution to be a dtrace solution.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon `/usr/bin/newproc.d` script. It's built-in to macOS. It's a big dtrace script.

`newproc.d | grep 'ifconfig\|route'`

in another shell:
`sudo route -n add -net 1.2.3.4/32 192.168.13.1`

```
2021 Sep  7 22:16:55 10460 <10458> 64b  route -n add -net 1.2.3.4/32 192.168.13.1
2021 Sep  7 22:17:04 10463 <10462> 64b  route -n delete -net 1.2.3.4/32
```